# MVC 5 creating new ViewModel not keeping property settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of refactoring some code for a site and I'm trying to reduce repetitive code.

I setup a ViewModel and then made and override that would populate properties. When I debug I can step through and see that when the new object is created it will populate but as soon as it comes back to the controller there are no properties set. I thought I could populate properties like this any time I create a new object.

```
namespace VTC.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class VtcCommentViewModel
    {
        DataAccess DAL = new DataAccess();

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string ReaderName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string CommentStatus { get; set; }    
        public List<PunchList> PunchList { get; set; }


        public VtcCommentViewModel()
        { }

        public VtcCommentViewModel(Auth_Admin auth)
        {
            ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

            VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel();
            vm.EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
            vm.EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
            vm.ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
            vm.PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my controller. When I debug through the creation of the new ViewModel I can see it populate the properties but when I look at the `View(vm)` then the `vm` is empty.

```
public ActionResult Comments()
{
    VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel(auth);
    SetPageTitle("Enter Exception Log Comments");

    return View(vm);
}
```

***UPDATE***

Not sure if this would be good design or not but I moved the populating of the properties from the ViewModel constructor to a function in the controller.

This is what I have in my controller now and it seems to work.

```
public ActionResult Comments()
{
    VtcCommentViewModel vm = populateCommentVM(auth);
    SetPageTitle("Enter Exception Log Comments");

    return View(vm);
}

private VtcCommentViewModel populateCommentVM(Auth_Admin auth)
{
    ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

    VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel();
    vm.EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
    vm.EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
    vm.ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
    vm.Comment = string.Empty;
    vm.PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);

    return vm;
}
```

Comment: Between the `View(vm)` and the new `vm` the properties are set?

Comment: Your ViewModel should *not* have access to (or even know about) your DAL, ideally. You want to be passing the values to the constructor down from your Controller, and populating your properties that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You creating a new object `VtcCommentViewModel` inside your constructor, and assigning the properties to that new object

```
    public VtcCommentViewModel(Auth_Admin auth)
    {
        ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

        VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel();
// here you are creating a new object - WRONG!
        vm.EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
        vm.EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
        vm.ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
        vm.PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);
    }
```

Should be this

```
    public VtcCommentViewModel(Auth_Admin auth)
    {
        ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

        // assign values to property of the object you are creating - not a new object
        EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
        EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
        ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
        PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);
    }
```

Note: Your View Model should not Know about your DAL - seems like some bad architecture

Comment: Removing the creation of the new object seemed to fix it. I'll look at getting the data in the controller and passing it down to the VM.

Comment: I made a change to my controller and posted it as an UPDATE to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Besides including DAL access in your vm, you have some flaws on the constructor:

```
        ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

        // Wrong! You are creating a new instance which dies when you left the constructor!
        VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel();
        vm.EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
        vm.EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
        vm.ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
        vm.PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);
```

Fix:

```
        ValidETMResult validEtm = DAL.ValidateETM(auth.CurrentUser, auth.CurrentIP);

        // Wrong! You are creating a new instance which dies before you exit the constructor!
        // Nop VtcCommentViewModel vm = new VtcCommentViewModel();
        this.EmployeeName = validEtm.emp_name;
        this.EmployeeNumber = auth.CurrentUser;
        this.ReaderName = validEtm.rdr_name;
        this.PunchList = DAL.GetPunchList(auth.CurrentUser);
```

Try to get a helper class which loads your data into your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth to consider is to usage of [Factory Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) or [Builder Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern). Additional as others already tell VM should not know about DAL [Separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).